# When downloading a file with PHP, nothing happens?

Tags: php

I'm having trouble downloading a remote file via PHP.

I've tried using cURL and streaming, neither of which produces an error.

Here's my current code for streaming.

```
$url = "http://commissiongeek.com/files/text.txt";
$path = "/files/cb.txt";     
file_put_contents($path, file_get_contents($url));
```

I'll be downloading a zip file when I get this working, but in theory this should work just fine...

The folder's permissions are set to 777, and as said before, no errors are being thrown.
What could cause this?

Comment: Add at the beginning of your script: `ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);` What error do you get?

Comment: Check in your error logs of apache

Comment: Maybe your server has been configured in that way you don't have rights to access external files trough those functions.

Comment: My error logs are clean and I've got my code set to log all errors to a file instead of displaying them. I think HostGator has my server restricted in terms of functions. I'm contacting them now.

Answer (score 1):

Split this up into multiple sections, so you can verify that each stage is working:

```
$url = 'http://...';
$txt = file_get_contents($url);
var_dump($txt);
var_dump(file_put_contents('/files/cb.txt', $txt));
```

The first dump SHOULD show you whatever that text that url returns. The second dump should output a boolean true/false depending on if the file_put failed or not.

Comment: Getting this response... "NULL bool(false)" Looks like it's not getting the file for some reason. Perhaps my host has those functions disabled.

Comment: Nevermind, I made a mistake copying the code over and the response is different now... "string(25) "This is just a text file." bool(false)" The file_put_contents is still false though.

Comment: Then there's your problem - php can't write to that file for some reason. the permissions and/or path are bad. Don't forget that even if the folder is 777, the `cb.txt` file may already be there and NOT be writeable by the webserver.

Comment: Nope, still not working. I'm talking with my host now, I think the function just isn't enabled.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have an absolute path that you are trying to save in. I believe you want the path changed to "files/cb.txt" instead and do not have any access to /files/

Answer (score 0):

If you have allow_url_fopen set to true:

```
$url = 'http://example.com/image.php';
$img = '/my/folder/flower.gif';
file_put_contents($img, file_get_contents($url));
```

Else use cURL:

```
$ch = curl_init('http://example.com/image.php');
$fp = fopen('/my/folder/flower.gif', 'wb');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: Thanks Blakdronzer. I've tried cURL with the same result. I'm talking with my host about the problem now.